# Single Cell RNASeq Knee Plot - Collapsed vs Non-collapsed Reads

Tags: scrnaseq, barcode, umi

I am trying to adapt combinatorial index reads with some modifications for long read sequencing; it's a custom approach, not a commercial kit.

I have a question about using Knee Plot for identifying Barcode white list for non-10X data. While generating the Knee Plot barcode which barcode frequencies should be used: without collapsing PCR replicates to after collapsing PCR replicates?

I have used UMI-Tools (https://umi-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/QUICK_START.html) and Pacbio groupdedup based approach. For the knee plot generation I used both collapsed and non-collapsed reads. Since its long reads and coverage is not great; bumps are not the perfect one but both inputs generate it. I am not sure which input I should consider to remove the backgrounds.

Thanks

**EDIT:** *Can the down-voters please leave a note why they think this not a good query to ask?*

Comment: You're providing information as a trickle instead of providing all relevant information including what you've tried right in the post. One needs to read all comments to understand your position. Hence the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you have UMIs, then cell/UMI/mapped transcript triplets should be collapsed into unique triplets.

Comment: I was looking at UMI Tools white list function; somehow it looks to me it consider all the reads for knee plot.